# Remote Web Driver: using proxy in Chrome and Opera

Tags: java, webdriver

I need to test webapp in different browsers (FF, IE, Chrome, Opera) with proxy,
but now i can do it only in FF and IE.

I know three ways to start RemoteWebDriver with proxy

1 way:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl(pacURL);

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.<browser>();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

wd = new RemoteWebDriver(wdURL, cap);
```

2 way:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort);

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.<browser>();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

wd = new RemoteWebDriver(wdURL, cap);
```

3 way: set system properties for Selenium Server (i can't use it because i don't know proxy port before test starts (proxy opens from test) and one Selenium Server can be used by many different tests in one time, and each of them must use different proxy).

In FF works 1 and 2 methods.
In IE only 2.

Chrome doesn't support 1 and 2 methods, and i think because it use onle system proxy settings. And because of it i can run tests only on my local machine, one test for time.

Opera has it's own proxy settings, but 1 and 2 methods don't work!

How to start Opera (and maybe Chrome) via RWD with proxy settings?

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of [ChromeDriver](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list) supports the WebDriver proxy capability. See http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/CapabilitiesAndSwitches. Not sure about Opera.